# Easing smooth using AS3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I was wondering if there was a way to ease the zoom effect when a mouse hovers an object using AS3.0. I know you can do it with movieclips but I want to use just AS3.0 to keep my file as compact as possible!

The code I'm using right now is very simple.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

my_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouse_over);
my_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouse_out);

function mouse_over(evt:MouseEvent){
    my_mc.width = 200;
    my_mc.height = 200;
}

function mouse_out(evt:MouseEvent){
    my_mc.width = 90;
    my_mc.height = 90;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use tweens. I suggest you take a look at [TweenLite](https://greensock.com/tweenlite-as). Your code would look as the following:

```
function mouse_over(evt:MouseEvent){
    TweenLite.to(my_mc, {width:200, height:200, ease:Cubic.easeInOut});
}

function mouse_out(evt:MouseEvent){
    TweenLite.to(my_mc, {width:90, height:90, ease:Cubic.easeInOut});
}
```

Comment: You may want to actually specify some easing (as that's what the question is really about).  I don't recall what tween lite defaults to, but it may be linear.  `Quad.easeInOut` or `Quint.easeInOut` would probably look nice.   Also, it's also good to explain that `TweenLite` is not free*.   If you use it in an application that charged the end user a fee, you are require to license it.   There is however, many alternatives, including the built-in `Tween` class (which would also keep file size down a bit).   TweenLite is the best and most mature one though (at least in my opinion)